# Installing iwidgets in Jupyter lab 4.0.11?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am relatively new to programming with python and I need to use the widgets package to plot some time-variable figures.

I installed Jupyter lab on my new macOS ( first time using a macOS) and the iwidgets but when I type:

```
$ Jupyter --version
```

I get ipywidgets not installed (The following info).

```
IPython          : 8.20.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.0
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.7.1
jupyter_server   : 2.12.5
jupyterlab       : 4.0.11
nbclient         : 0.9.0
nbconvert        : 7.14.2
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : not installed
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.14.1
```

any chance you can help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: To insure it gets installed to the correct environment where your kernel is running, you can try `%pip install ipywidgets` (assuming you aren't using Anaconda/conda because you didn't raise that as an issue) in a new cell in the notebook where you are trying to use it. Then restart the kernel and refresh the page in your browser and see if running the import (`import ipywidgets`) works in your notebook. If that works, you have installed it at least. It may still not work 100% though as ipywidgets is a rather complex installation. You may need to shut down your browser, your Jupyter, ....

Comment: <continued> and even your computer and start everything back up to insure all the changes involved get propagated to every where.  Then widgets should display correctly upon restart of Jupyter and that particular notebook next time.